# In Keras model fit which parameters can tell whether Data is wrong or model is not good

Tags: keras

I am training a simple model in keras for label classification task with following code. 
This dataset has 5 classes so final layer of the network has 5 outputs. 
Labels are also one-hot encoded. Here are my results:

```
32/4000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2264 - acc: 
0.8750
2176/4000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3092 - acc: 
0.8755
4000/4000 [==============================] - 0s 26us/step - loss: 0.2870 - 
acc: 0.8805 - val_loss: 15.9636 - val_acc: 0.0070
Epoch 99/100

32/4000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1408 - acc: 
0.9688
2176/4000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2696 - acc: 
0.8824
4000/4000 [==============================] - 0s 25us/step - loss: 0.2729 - 
acc: 0.8868 - val_loss: 15.9731 - val_acc: 0.0070
Epoch 100/100

32/4000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2299 - acc: 
0.9375
2176/4000 [===============>..............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2861 - acc: 
0.8787
4000/4000 [==============================] - 0s 25us/step - loss: 0.2763 - 
acc: 0.8865 - val_loss: 15.9791 - val_acc: 0.0070

 10/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s
 1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s 26us/step

 32/5000 [..............................] - ETA: 0s
 5000/5000 [==============================] - 0s 9us/step
```

When do tests at the end of training I get almost 100% error on the test data
I have looked at many related posts, but could not figure out what is wrong, but no luck.

Any advice ?

Comment: your NN fails to generalize to your new data meaning that your model is either underfitted or overfitted. If your model is underfitted it means that your model fails to capture the underlying relation between your input and desired output (try increasing size of network, lowering learning rate or provide new input to the model). If the model overfits it means that your data is trained 'too much', try introducing noice by i.e. adding a dropout layer in your NN or by a callback to a early stop function when your accuracy doing training does not improve. Looking at your data I think underfitting

Comment: Actually you can see that during training the val_acc is VERY low, meaning that your model is definitely underfitting.

Comment: Do you set the learning rate before model.fit or before model.compile ?

Comment: You mean by increasing size of NN to increase neurons in each hidden layer or to add more hidden layers or both ?

Comment: What do you mean by providing new input to the model ? instead of having 8 inputs, I should have 9 inputs for example ?

Comment: 1) you specify learning rate when choosing which optimizer to use (see [keras documentaion](https://keras.io/optimizers/) 
2) Its hard to tell exactly why your NN is underfitting since we do not have much code or data to tell from, but yes you could try to increase the neurons in each hidden layer or add more layers. Remember the 'complexer' a network the harder it is to train therefore start out simple.
3) I mean that you should really think about the data you give to your network i.e is all input data really necessary to predict the output? If not remove or transform the data